abp.ajax call fails when I migrate my ASP.NET boilerplate MVC web app from .NET Framework to ASP.NET Core
I have a ASP.NET boilerplate 7.4 MVC app using .NET framework 4.6 and that now I'm migrating to ASP.NET Core 6 (.NET6).
To do it, I started from a new ASP.NET Core MVC project generated with the website wizard (see https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates) and now I'm migrating all my original code to the brand new web app.
So far everything works, but now I'm facing a problem in invoking an MVC controller via Abp.ajax javascript function.
This is the MVC Controller:
    public class BookMgmController : AbpController {
        ...

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> Pay(PayRequestVM input) {
            ...
        }
    }

with:
    public class PayRequestVM {
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerSurname { get; set; }
        public bool PayAllAmount { get; set; }
    }

Well, in the legacy MVC app I successfully invoke it via js in this way:
    var input = {
        customerName: 'Gino',
        customerSurname: 'Latino',
        payAllAmount: true
    };

    abp.ajax({
        url: '/BookMgm/Pay',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(input)
    });

The problem is that when I test the same code in the new ASP.NET Core app, the Pay method of the controller fails because of the properties of input PayRequestVM object on c# side are all null (or false).
Note that the problem is only when I call a MVC controller method via js. Infact, if I POST anything (via js) to my remote app services (web api) everything works.
I suspect it's an initial configuration problem of the MVC part. Missing 'camel case' config? Something else? I'm going crazy...

After a deep investigation I finally found the solution:
I needed to decorate the method with the [FromBody] attribute in this way:
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Pay([FromBody] PayRequestVM input) {
        ...
    }

In ASP.NET Core, the [FromBody] attribute explicitly tells the model binder to look for data in the request body. Without [FromBody] model binding looks at various sources including the query string and form data, but it expects the JSON data to match the parameter of the action method exactly.
A good explanation here.
